# Which method to update component on data change?

Tags: java, swing, javabeans, datamodel

I have a component which displays property of some (external) bean. I.e. bean is backing the component. Now I want to update picture periodically. Of course I can write my own method to update. But may be there is one in ideology of swing?

Which pattern is usually used in swing when data model was updated and now it is required to reflect new data in visual form?

Comment: everything if is there PropertyChangeSupport, then you can to add PropertychangeListener, another way is ChangeListener or every JComponents has own listener that notified about changes in Model

Comment: Three common approaches are mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513) in the context of the observer pattern.